# Starting wso2 enterprise integrator server from EI Tool

Tags: eclipse, wso2, wso2-esb

I'm starting a new project with Enterprise Integrator 6.0 and so far I'm unable to start a server from within the eclipse distribution that comes with the EI Tool.

When I was working with ESB, I used to create a server and create a Runtime environment pointing the `CARBON_HOME` variable to `<ESB_INTALLATION_DIR>/bin`, but if I do the same with Enterprise Integrator I get the following error:

`Configuration error
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\...\wso2ei-6.0.0\repository\conf\etc\logging-bridge.properties (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager.readConfiguration(ClassLoaderLogManager.java:466)
    at   org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager.readConfiguration(ClassLoaderLogManager.java:311)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.readPrimordialConfiguration(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.access$800(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.ensureLogManagerInitialized(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.getLogManager(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.demandLogger(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jmx.remote.util.ClassLogger.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.management.jmxremote.ConnectorBootstrap.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.management.Agent.startLocalManagementAgent(Unknown Source)
    at sun.management.Agent.startAgent(Unknown Source)
    at sun.management.Agent.startAgent(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.wso2.carbon.server.Main
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.wso2.carbon.bootstrap.Bootstrap.loadClass(Bootstrap.java:59)
    at org.wso2.carbon.bootstrap.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:45)
    Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0`

I'm able to start the EI server from the console, but in the long run it would be way easier to work directly from eclipse. Can anyone shed a light on how to do this configuration?
I'm running on java jdk 1.8.0_25, windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently the default arguments used by eclipse in the launch configuration was all wrong.It was using the file structure for ESB projects, and that's what caused the `FileNotFoundException`.For example, the default server configuration would have something like

`-Dconf.location="<CARBON_HOME>/repository/conf"`

When it should be:

`-Dconf.location="<CARBON_HOME>\conf"`

I found this after some digging with the `integrator.bat` script. Information about the configuration differences between ESB and EI can be found [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI600/Upgrading+from+WSO2+Enterprise+Service+Bus).

-EDIT-

It seems these problems are going o be [fixed in the next release](https://github.com/wso2/product-ei/issues/325#event-1012042887)